# Regexp, how to limit a match

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
string = %q{<span class="no">2503</span>read_attribute_before_type_cast(<span class="pc">self</span>.class.primary_key)}
```

In this example I want to match the words 'class' which are not in the tag. Regexp for this:

```
/\bclass[^=]/
```

But the problem is that it matches the last letter

```
/\bclass[^=]/.match(string) => 'class.'
```

I don't want have a last dot in a result. I've tried this regexp:

```
/\bclass(?:[^=])/
```

but still got the same result. How to limit the result to 'class'? Thanks

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/38765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct, but you have an error in your look ahead. Try this:

```
/\bclass(?!=)/
```

The regex term `(?!=)` means the input to the right must not match the character '='

Answer (score 0):

You can take your variable *string* and extract a subsection using groups:

```
substring = string[/\b(class)[^=]/, 1]
```

The brackets around *class* will set that as the first "group", which is referred to by the 1 as the second parameter in the square brackets.

Comment: Clumsy. Use a (non-consuming) regex look ahead - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your only issue is keeping it from matching span.class.blah, just ignore . as well, so `[^=.]`.